# Displaying Facebook username in Navigation drawer activitys Navigation header layout in textview

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, navigation-drawer, textview

[image: My navigation Header layout]

[image: My main code where i want to use it]

i dont know how to use it can anyone explain me how this can be done i already use some solutions but didnt work it does not show me the name on textview but i displayed in toast it is displaying and i inflate the view but still cant used then i programmatically hardcode string my app is crashing now please help me to find a suitable solution for this problem

Comment: can you mention logcats?

Comment: can you be precise what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.your_navigation_view_id);//navigation view id
View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView tv= (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

**Then use**

```
tv.setText("");
```

**inside the onCompleted() method.**

Comment: can you explain this line of code View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); the index you passed 0 is of what ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 changes

1 -  set your **Textview** below **View header**

2 - also make **header.findViewById(R.id.text)** in Textview

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view); 
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); 
TextView tv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.text)
```

Comment: it is showing name in toast already but not in my navigation header Textview

Comment: Nikunj I have to use textview in my graphrequest oncompleted overided method to pass th name in tv

Comment: no need to change in onCompleted method...only make 'findViewById' below 'View header' as I set in answer

Comment: NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView tv = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.text)

Answer (score 0):

you should write this code in your main activity onCreate:

```
 View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView signuplogin = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.signuplogin);
    signuplogin.setText(R.string.signup_login);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have another TextView with the name of "tv" but defined as a field. (Most probably at the top of your class)

Remove the field, and give it a try.